# Where does Drupal save the trim length for the body field?

Tags: nodes

When I navigate to *Manage display* for any node type that has a standard body field and click on the *Teaser* tab the default format will be "Summary or trimmed". The default trim length is 600 (characters), but you can change it to whatever you want and *Save* the new value.

However, I want to know *where* (i.e. in which table or variable) this value is saved.

(I need this information in order to find out what trim length to use when *comments* are emailed to users that subscribe to comment notifications. The project specification requests comment notifications to be trimmed to *same* length as the content type they're attached to.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Drupal 7, field settings are saved into `{field_config_instance}` and `{field_config}` database table.

Trim length for a body field is saved in the `data` column in the `{field_config_instance}` table.  The `data` column is stored in BLOB format, so you are not able to see the value of this.

You can use the [`field_info_instance()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7) function to extract information about a particular field in a particular entity bundle/type:

```
$body = field_info_instance('node', 'body', 'page');  
print_r($body);
```

Comment: I think it would be more accurate to say that `{field_config_instance.data}` is stored as serialized data in a `BLOB`, and not binary.

Comment: @MPD, Oh sorry. You are right.

Comment: @MPD, I have updated my answer.